# 301 redirect subdomain into file in the same directory (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In the root folder I have:

```
/
  users.php
  admin.php
  index.php
```

I have subdomains setup

```
users.foo.com
admin.foo.com
foo.com
```

Im tryin gto setup a 301 so if someone goes to users.foo.com/admin.php it will redirect to 
users.foo.com instead of rendering the admin.php file

```
Redirect 301 users.foo.com/admin.php users.foo.com  #<-- this doesnt work
```

Is this possible with out having the "index" files all in the same folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't put host information in a `Redirect` directive, you can use mod_rewrite for that though:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^admin\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```